# @Published doesn't work as expected with enviornment object and nested ObservableObejct

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

Say I have `UserSettings` `EnviornmentObject` and one of it's properties is a class, the problem is when I change a value of that class, the `EnviornmentObject` won't publish these changes. I understand why, but I can't seem to find a workaround.

Here is a simplified code to show the problem:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("test: \(self.settings.ob.val)")

            VStack {
                // This is the only one that works and that makes sense, it changes the entire object
                Button(action: {
                    self.settings.changeOb(to: testOb(val: "1"))
                }) {
                    Text("Change object")
                }

                // From here on nothing works, I tried different ways to change the object value

                Button(action: {
                    self.settings.ob.changeVal(to: "2")
                }) {
                    Text("Change object's val")
                }

                Button(action: {
                    self.settings.changeVal(to: "3")
                }) {
                    Text("Change object's val V2")
                }

                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return ZStack {
            TestView().environmentObject(UserSettings(ob: testOb("abc")))
        }
    }
}

class testOb: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var val: String

    init(val: String) {
        self.val = val
    }

    func changeVal(to: String) {
        self.val = to
    }
}

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var ob: testOb

    init(ob: testOb) {
        self.ob = ob
    }

    func changeOb(ob: testOb) {
        self.ob = ob
    }


    func changeVal(to: String) {
        self.ob.val(to: to)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ob: testOb{
        willSet{
            observer.cancel()
        }
        didSet{
            observer = ob.objectWillChange.sink(){self.objectWillChange.send()}
        }
    }
    var observer: AnyCancellable!

    init(ob: testOb) {
        self.ob = ob
        self.observer = nil
        self.observer = ob.objectWillChange.sink(){self.objectWillChange.send()}
    }
    func sendChange(){

    }
    func changeOb(ob: testOb) {
        self.ob = ob
    }

    func changeVal(to: String) {
        self.ob.changeVal(to: to)
    }
    deinit {
        observer.cancel()
    }
}
```

`@Published` is for sending notifications, not for listening.

Or you can store a weak link to parent in child object and call `parent.objectWillChange.send()` in child's `willSet{}`.

Comment: you did nearly the same while I was playing with it in Xcode

Comment: haha yea, thank you for your efforts though. Highly appreciated, I will fix my code to match things from yours.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to fix it, the problem is that Apple doesn't support nested `ObesrvableObject`s along with many important features (which is sad but whatever) yet but as I heard, it's on their agenda.

The solution is that I have to manually notify everytime my object will change and this could be painful the more objects you have.

To notify we first need to import `Combine` so we can use `AnyCancellable` which is responsible for notifications.

Here is the updated code:

```
    // FIRST CHANGE
    import Combine

    struct TestView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Text("test: \(self.settings.ob.val)")

                VStack {
                    // This is the only one that works and that makes sense, it changes the entire object
                    Button(action: {
                        self.settings.changeOb(to: testOb(val: "1"))
                    }) {
                        Text("Change object")
                    }

                    // From here on nothing works, I tried different ways to change the object value

                    Button(action: {
                        self.settings.ob.changeVal(to: "2")
                    }) {
                        Text("Change object's val")
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        self.settings.changeVal(to: "3")
                    }) {
                        Text("Change object's val V2")
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            return ZStack {
                TestView().environmentObject(UserSettings(ob: testOb("abc")))
            }
        }
    }

    class testOb: ObservableObject {
        @Published private(set) var val: String

        init(val: String) {
            self.val = val
        }

        func changeVal(to: String) {
            self.val = to
        }
    }

    class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
        @Published private(set) var ob: testOb

        // SECOND CHANGE, this is responsible to notify on changes
        var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

        init(ob: testOb) {
            self.ob = ob

            // THIRD CHANGE, initialize our notifier
            anyCancellable = self.ob.objectWillChange.sink { (_) in
               self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }

        func changeOb(ob: testOb) {
            self.ob = ob
        }


        func changeVal(to: String) {
            self.ob.val(to: to)
        }
    }
```